# Binding listview to a lookup table

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a list view which is bound to a database table:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = tmpTable.DefaultView;
```

I have in the xaml file a text box which is bound to one of the columns of the data table tmpTable (ID):

```
<TextBlock Name="txtPath" Text="{Binding ID}"
```

The ID represents a full path in a lookup table called Input_Docs
I need txtPath to present the actual path from the lookup table Input_Docs.
How do I do that?

Comment: Perhaps it's clear for you, but I'm not sure anyone else can understand your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way of doing this would be to write a custom value converter which you can apply to `txtPath`. The converter will then get the `ID` value passed to it (I'm guessing that isn't a problem right now for you) and do the lookup in `Input_Docs` returning the corresponding value which will then be displayed by `txtPath`

For more information on using converters have a look at [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx), [Binding Converter Example](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/03/how-to-use-ivalueconverter-in-binding.html), [Lookup Converter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx)

I imagine the last URL will be most useful to you, but the other bits should give you an idea on the power of Converters.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way of doing this would be to write a custom value converter which you can apply to .
I imagine the last URL will be most useful to you, but the other bits should give you an idea on the power of Converters.